# How to replace / with \ in R

Tags: r, replace

How do replace / with single \ in R, e.g. "xx/xx" -> "xx\xx" ?

These do not work

```
> str_replace_all("xx/xx", "/", "\\")
[1] "xxxx"
> str_replace_all("xx/xx", "/", "\\\\")
[1] "xx\\xx"
```

Comment: `str_replace_all("xx/xx", "/", "\\\\")` is actually correct.  The first backslash you see in your result is the escape character (similar to how "\n" isn't an "n"). To verify, look at what happens when you wrap that code in `cat` (ie. `cat(str_replace_all("xx/xx", "/", "\\\\"))`)

Comment: In the second output `[1] "xx\\xx"` the two backslashes are not literal...there is only 1 backslash

Comment: Try `chartr("/", "\\", "xx/xx")`. @TimBiegeleisen right, the first backslash only escapes the second.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can replace the forward slash `"/"` with a single backslash `"\"` using the `gsub` function and the appropriate regular expression. Example:

```
original_string <- "xx/xx"
modified_string <- gsub("/", "\\\\", original_string)
```

After running this code, modified_string will contain "xx\xx", which is the desired output with a single backslash.